# Problemas com parse de campos herdados JAVAX WS CORE

Tags: java, java-ee, glassfish, jersey

Estou com um classe de retorno, que tem seus atributos definidos para devolver na resposta em json ou xml, dependendo da consulta.

Preciso inserir dois campos novos nesse retorno, porém eles são muito específicos, ou seja, outros serviços não vão utilizar,mas devido a abstração que temos, necessariamente preciso que o objeto de retorno seja o mesmo.

Pois bem, tive a ideia de estender um objeto a essa classe de retorno. algo como:

A classe mãe seria essa:

```
    public class Retorno implements Serializable {

/**
* 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

private String id;

private String descricao;
//getters and setters
}
```

E a classe filha:

```
public class RetornoExtendido extends Retorno {

/**
* 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected String detalheRetornoExtendido;
/getters and setters
}
```

Pois bem, tudo certo, a aplicação se comporta como o esperado e os atributos estão preenchidos corretamente.

Porém, no momento de fazer o parse para json, os campos da classe filha são ignorados, ficaria algo como:

```
{
"retorno": {
    "id": 1,
    "descricao": "alguma decricao"
}
```

}

mesmo o campo da classe filha estando preenchido.

a classe de de retorno definida para o Response Builder, é a classe mãe.

algo como

```
Response.status(Status.OK).entity(retorno).build();
```

Sendo Retorno definido como:`Retorno retorno = servico.processarRetorno(parametros);`

onde o processarRetorno devolve uma instancia da classe filha.

Não encontrei nada relacionado e pra mim isso não faz muito sentido, talvez eu esteja me perdendo em algum detalhe.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro como você gera o retorno mas me parece um problema que pode ser resolvido usando padrão de projeto Decorator. Simplificadamente em vez de estender a classe mãe você cria uma interface:

```
public interface Retorno implements Serializable { 
   // seus métodos 
   public String retornaJson();
}
```

Sua classe mãe então implementa Retorno:

```
ṕublic class RetornoImpl implements Retorno { 

   // implementação atual 
   public String retornaJson {// }
}
```

Sua classe Decorator também implementa Retorno mas tem um construtor que recebe também uma classe que implementa Retorno:

```
public class RetornoDecorator implements Retorno {
      Retorno retorno = retorno;
      public RetornoDecorator(Retorno retorno) {
         this.retorno = retorno;
      }

      // implementações da interface Retorno usam as implementações do campo retorno
      public String retornajson {
           return this.retorno.retornaJson(); 
      }
     
}
```

No uso você deve estender a classe RetornoDecorator:

```
public class RetornoDecoratorEstendido extends RetornoDecorator {
     public RetornoDecoratorEstendido(Retorno retorno) {
          super(retorno);
     }

     public String retornaJson() {
          return super.retornaJson() + " retornoJsonEstendido ";
     }     
}
```

Repare que todas elas implementam a interface Retorno o que facilita o refactoring do código e novas extensões que forem criadas. Para saber mais, veja sobre padrão [Decorator](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator) na wikipedia (mais completo em [inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)).

Comment: Vou fazer esse teste Emerson, muito obrigado, não tinha pensado nesse padrão. Porém como você falou que não ficou muito claro, a questão da herança funciona, eu tenho os campos preenchidos, porém no resolver do Moxy para transformar o objeto que eu seto na Response em Json/XML, esses campos da classe filha são ignorados, mesmo estando preenchidos. De qualquer forma, vou fazer esse teste! mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Não esqueça de atualizar a gente com a solução ou atualizar a questão com novas informações para que a comunidade possa ajudar.